# Will static variables with same name in two seperate function conflict?

Tags: c++

I am a noob, this may be a foolish question, but
any views and help would be highly appreciated.
say I have

```
static int i=10;
int f(){
static int i=1;
i++; // which i
}
int main(){
static int i=20;
i++; // which i, how to go to global i?
}
```

also as i understand static variables are not stored in activation records, instead in seperate place where global variables of programs are stored, if all i are there, how does compiler differentiate?

thanks in advance

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages with different rules and behaviours.

Comment: That's the compiler's job, to worry about these things. It is not necessary to know all these low-level details in order to write well-formed C++ code.

Comment: Use `::i++` to increment the global `i`.

Comment: this is C++ @kaylum

Comment: Then don't tag with `C`. They are not the same language.

Comment: @LoveleenSingh Don't tag is as C then. C tag removed.

Comment: thanks @john , got it

Comment: I would also like to know how is it different in C from C++

Comment: @LoveleenSingh Well you can't use the *scope resolution operator* `::` in C. As far as I know there's no way to access the global `i` in C.